# Which layer should contain ICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

In WPF, I have a ViewModel class called Malfunctions, and it has an ObservableCollection of PartMalfunctions. Typically, there are anywhere between 10 to 15 PartMalfunction objects in the ObservableCollection; how many there are depends upon other parameters that are outside the scope of this question.

I have some xaml that has a DataGrid which binds to this ObservableCollection. In the DataGrid I display various properties of the PartMalfuction (ie - description, name, etc.) and I have a Start timer button that the user can click. The Start timer button is bound to the **ICommand StopwatchCmd** in the PartMalfunction Model class (you can see all of this below in the code).

Here is my question: **Do I have the StopwatchCmd in the wrong layer (ie - Does it belong in the Malfunctions ViewModel)?** I have really struggled with this and tried to figure it out on my own, but I keep hitting a wall, so to speak, because the StopwatchCmd in the Model class works great! I mean it's able to execute there and perform whatever business rules it needs to and interact with just that instance of the object for which it fired. If I stick it in the ViewModel then it seems like I have to go through more work to get it to do what it's already doing.

Please note that I have left out some code from the Malfunctions ViewModel as it's not related to this question. Here is the code to the Malfunctions ViewModel.

```
public class Malfunctions : ViewModelBase {
       public ObservableCollection<Model.PartMalfunction> AllPartMalfunctions {
            get;
            private set;
        }
}
```

The Model class for PartMalfunction looks something like this:

```
public class PartMalfunction : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private int _seconds;
    private string _stopwatchText = string.Empty;
    private bool _isStopwatchInProgress = false;
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    RelayCommand _stopwatchCmd;

    public ICommand StopwatchCmd {
        get {
            if (_stopwatchCmd == null)
                _stopwatchCmd = new RelayCommand(param => this.StopwatchClick());
            return _stopwatchCmd;
        }
    }
    public bool IsStopwatchInProgress {
        get {
            return _isStopwatchInProgress;
        }
        set {
            _isStopwatchInProgress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsStopwatchInProgress");
        }
    }
    public string StopwatchText {
        get {
            return _stopwatchText;
        }
        set {
            _stopwatchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StopwatchText");
        }
    }
    private void StopwatchClick() {

        if (!this.IsStopwatchInProgress) {
            // Start the timer
            _seconds = 0;

            // Will immediately update the timer text to "00:00:00"
            this.StopwatchText = GetElapsed();

            _timer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
            _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // Ticks every second
            _timer.Start();

            this.IsStopwatchInProgress = true;
        }
        else {
            // Stop the timer
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Tick -= DispatcherTimer_Tick;
            _seconds = 0;

            this.IsStopwatchInProgress = false;
        }
    }
    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        _seconds += 1;

        this.StopwatchText = GetElapsed();
    }
    private string GetElapsed() {
        int hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;

        if (_seconds > 59) {
            min = (int)_seconds / 60;
            sec = _seconds % 60;

            if (min > 59) {
                hour = (int)min / 60;
                min = min % 60;
            }
        }
        else
            sec = _seconds;

        string elapsed = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour.ToString() : hour.ToString();
        elapsed += ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" + min.ToString() : min.ToString());
        elapsed += ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec.ToString() : sec.ToString());

        return elapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: For me what you think is a Model is in fact a ViewModel, to be more specific the parent ViewModel (Malfunctions) has a collection of child ViewModels (PartMalfunction) exposed as a collection (ObservableCollection<T>), meaning there isn't problem with the ICommand properties on the PartMalfunction class.

Comment: @AwkwardCoder - I see what you're saying. So this really could just be a problem with my perception of what is a Model or a ViewModel. Do you mind putting your comment as an answer?

Comment: okay, I'll put it as an answer but the question could be perceived as primarily opinion based :)

Comment: You can do it either way. It's no big deal. Don't start navel-gazing like this; you may never stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I organize it in `MVVM`:

- Models : only entities, partials of classes which are consumed.
- View :  Xaml and code behind which may show/manipulate Models as provided by the View Model.
- ViewModel : This layer is where the **business** logic resides and data (the models) retrieved from the DB are stored. It is the *conduit between the View and the Models*. It can access databases, create timers, hold ICommands,.... as long as the **what** it relates to business logic. No direct view processing; per-se (See implementation).

Remember when three tier systems were all the rage? If you think of MVVM as three tiers that may help. IMHO

---

> Which layer should contain ICommand?

The viewmodel should hold the reference, because it handles the *business logic* of what the command does. But...

#### Implementation

The implementation of the command can be held in the View or on the ViewModel based on the needs of the command. I have frequently defined the references in the VM to then provide actual processing in the View which has stateful View values to be processed during runtime.

Comment: For me I would disagree with the idea of 'this layer is where the business logic resides'. ViewModels are more like Controllers in the classic sense of MVC and are there to orchestrate a process. The actual business logic is contained in a Model and\or a set of Service classes that populate\update a Model. But this is just an opinion :)

Comment: @AwkwardCoder I think your thoughts are valid and I am pragmatic in that, one can't fully require a *one size fits all* rule for all situations. I felt that my *opionion* was subtly different, so I threw it in the ring. Good answer on your part.  :-)

Comment: This is all very difficult, and doubly so due to the slight differences in understanding as to what comprises a Model and a ViewModel. I followed a video online that showed how to setup MVVM in a WPF application, and the maker of the video had his Model classes being consumed as objects in ObservableCollections. That's why I'm getting so confused with this!

Comment: @Jagd To someone new `MVVM` seems like a monolithic concept. But really don't sweat the details. My system as proposed, simply lumps all the operations into the VM. I would have the models held in ObservableCollections in the VM, for it also *holds* data as well as business logic processing. HTH

Comment: What if you want to re-use a task or work-flow? Writing business logic into a specific view (model) might led you to WET instead of simply DRY.

Comment: I mean WET as `write everything twice´ and DRY as `don't repeat yourself´, of course :)

Comment: @JPollack Maybe the interpretation of business logic is in the eye of the beholder. If one has specific operations then it is best to have those operations in a separate library and are simply *initiated* from the VM. Hence you have a DRY situation. Regardless the VM is the place one would look to see the **execution** of operations geared towards the business logic, more so that the View Or the Model.

Answer (score 4):

This question could be perceived as being primarily as opinion based, but I do believe it helps less experience developers understand the boundaries of the Model-View-ViewModel.

For me what you think is a Model is in fact a ViewModel, to be more specific the parent ViewModel (Malfunctions) has a collection of child ViewModels (PartMalfunction) exposed as a collection (ObservableCollection), meaning there isn't problem with the ICommand properties on the PartMalfunction class.

If I find a Model class doing a lot of format of data for display (text, dates etc) then it is more likely to be a ViewModel, this kind of thing is the responiblity of the ViewModel. Also for me a Model class does not implment the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, notifications are done using events (or Rx streams) and the subscriber (ViewModel) can then choose how and when to update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

`ICommand` has two interesting members. `Execute`, which defines an action that another object can request that the owner of the command do, and `CanExecute`, which defines whether or not another should request the action. This is very apparent in the names of `ICommand`'s properties, but if you look carefully, they land `ICommand` a perfect home in the ViewModel layer. Your view models can expose some actions, with control over when they are allowed to execute, to an unknown view. Since commands are generally public properties on the view model, you can easily bind to them from WPF controls without any tight coupling. `Button` for example, can bind to a command to define what it does without needing to know what type its `DataContext`(view model) is.

If you tried to place your `ICommand` in your view, you might find that they would be cumbersome compared to a method, since views have access to their own methods. Because of this, `ICommand` is not well suited in the View layer.

Since your view model abstracts the model away from your model (ideally), you wouldn't be able to (and wouldn't want to) put commands on your model classes. Any logic that deals with being presented or interacted with does not belong in the model layer.